# How to handle daylight savings when scheduling future events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar, dst

I am working on a website that posts events throughout the year. We offer an .ICS download so visitors can add the events to their calendars.

We recently discovered that visitors are reporting the time to be off (plus or minus one hour depending on their location) for events that occur after March 11. Basically, this is the "true" time that the event will occur given the time-shift, but the issue is that the event was scheduled for a specific time that should not be adjusted.

How does one get around this issue? All my attempts to compensate by adding or subtracting an hour have resulted in it breaking for either East coast or West coast.

Possible related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484447/scheduling-events-and-daylight-savings-time

UPDATE: here is the code I am using:

```
// Create calendar and add the desired timezone
DDay.iCal.iCalendar iCal = new DDay.iCal.iCalendar();
var targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzid);
iCal.AddTimeZone(targetTimeZone);

// Create the event and add it to the calendar
DDay.iCal.Event evt = iCal.Create<DDay.iCal.Event>();

// Adjust the start/end date by one hour if the dates/times fall under daylight savings in the target timezone
if (targetTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(endDt))
    endDt = endDt.AddHours(-1);
evt.DTEnd = new iCalDateTime(endDt, tzid);

if (targetTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(startDt))
    startDt = startDt.AddHours(-1);
evt.DTStart = new iCalDateTime(startDt, tzid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to omit the timezone completely from the iCalendar and use UTC date/times.

Comment: I know this is a couple years old, but you will have 1 hour discrepancies in an edge case I'm dealing with right now. If an event is scheduled during DST for a time in the future that is not DST, once DST changes later that year, that date entered previously will now appear off by one hour. And vice-versa for not DST to a time in DST, of course, off by 1 hour the other direction.

Comment: @Bon I would recommend using NodaTime. It has the updated DST schedules and when you convert to/from local timezone it automatically subtracts/adds the correct offset based on whether DST is on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide the datetime information in a format which contains the timezone also, example: "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT" or "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00"

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with some example code. I'm not sure if the system I am using is storing the dates as UTC or not...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to handle scheduling future events when daylight savings is concerned...

Say you're on the east coast, your time-zone is EST (that is, GMT-5), and after March 11th it's EDT (GMT-4). If you schedule an event for 11AM on March 15th, do you want it to take place at 5PM GMT (that is, 11AM EST) or 4PM GMT (that is, 11AM EDT) ?

If it's the first, you should keep doing what it is you're doing. If it's the second, you can just subtract 1 hour from the time. Just think of all the times as GMT times, and you'll avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks. The later is what I'm aiming for, however, if I subtract an hour and download the .ICS from the West coast, it compensates in the wrong direction, scheduling the event 5 hours ahead (instead of 3). Subtracting one hour _does_ fix it for the East coast, however.

Comment: Is the west coast moving to PDT at a later date, perhaps?

Comment: Using UTC is a good approach for handling events whose time is fully defined (e.g. March 28, 4:52pm).  It doesn't always help with daily or weekly events, though.  How much time is there between an event which happens every Sunday at 1:59am and one that happens at 3:01am?